# Using Hyperlink to Form in Custom Workflow Email

Tags: designer-workflow

I am sending emails to several staff in an approval process.  As each person approves the customized list form, an email is sent to the next person in line with a link to the form.  I would like the user to be taken back to the site's homepage instead of the list library after clicking the Approve, Reject, or Cancel buttons.

Any thoughts on how to craft the URL so that this will happen?  Or can I build it into the workflow or button rules in the InfoPath form?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `&source=http://yoursitehome` to the URL that should bring the user back to the home page of your site following their action.